# Do I have to clean up all dialogs 'show' by my activity

Tags: android

In my activity, I show a dialog under some condition like this:

```
public void showADialog(String title, String msg) {
    if (mIsActivityRunning) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .show();
    }
}
```

My question is what do I need to do to ensure there is no resource leak? From the logcat, i see there is a case where it said a window is leaking or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the dialog box closes, how are you dismissing it? If you are using the `hide()` method, this won't actually dismiss the dialog.

**EDIT:** You need to dispose of the dialog box as the Activity is disposed of - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added) for more details

Comment: what if I just call dialog.show(), and then I just do a screen rotation? or I launch another activity. Does that mean I need to close/destory my dialog manually? or android does it for me?